# How to split Rsyslog MSG by REGEX expression

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I have syslog message from my device. I am using Rsyslog and want to collect specific message from a specific folder using REGEX expression.

The configuration with the old syntax works as intended:

```
:msg, regex, "hostname0. %%01SHELL" /var/log/tel/hostname.log
```

... which produces the following logs (example):

`Feb  1 17:41:18 hostname01 %%01SHELL/6/DISPLAY_CMDRECORD(s)[5461]: Recorded display command information. (Task=FW, Ip=**, VpnName=, User=_system_, AuthenticationMethod="Null", Command="display engine statistics system")`

`Feb  1 17:42:18 hostname02 %%01SHELL/6/DISPLAY_CMDRECORD(s)[5461]: Recorded display command information. (Task=FW, Ip=**, VpnName=, User=_system_, AuthenticationMethod="Null", Command="display engine statistics system")`

My template in the new RainerScript syntax, is not working:

```
template (name="HOST_SHELL" type="string" string="/var/log/tel/%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%-HOST-SHELL.log")

if re_match($msg, 'hostname0. %%01SHELL')
    then {action(type="omfile" dynaFile="HOST_SHELL")
stop
}
```

But, nothing happens. Maybe there is another way to solve the problem, or correct my template.

In the future planned to filter:

```
hostname0. %%01ERRORS in folder /var/log/tel/%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%-HOST-ERRORS.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In your RainerScript syntax configuration, you are missing the if statement's closing brace } before the stop statement. You should include it after the action statement like this:

```
template (name="HOST_SHELL" type="string" string="/var/log/tel/%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%-HOST-SHELL.log")

if re_match($msg, 'hostname0. %%01SHELL') then {
    action(type="omfile" dynaFile="HOST_SHELL")
    stop
}
```

Also, you may want to modify the regex pattern to include the dot character (.) in the hostname match pattern. The dot character has a special meaning in regex, and it matches any character. To match the literal dot character, you can escape it with a backslash (.). Here is an updated regex pattern:

```
if re_match($msg, 'hostname0\..* %%01SHELL') then {
    ...
}
```

This should match any message that starts with "hostname0." followed by any characters, then " %%01SHELL"